# Dynamically linking boost across multiple environments

Tags: c++, docker, boost, cmake

So I am trying to setup a run docker environment for a binary.
I am trying to keep the run docker image as small as possible.
The binary a dependency on boost, and is build using cmake

**Cmake**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

add_definitions(-DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB -DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK)
set(Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
find_package(Boost 1.70.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS locale exception serialization system timer regex
                                              thread program_options chrono filesystem iostreams)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} SYSTEM)
```

The boost is taken from the source tarball and built as its pretty new.
I build using my local machine (which can execute the binary no problem).
I then build a docker image where I also install/build the boost from source and copy the binary from my local machine into the docker.

When I execute within docker I am getting missing symbols when running the binary.

**Inside Docker - binary run**

```
root@200f0fb753fc:/opt/bin# ./run_bin
./run_bin: symbol lookup error: ./run_bin: undefined symbol: _ZN5boost9iostreams4zlib6finishE
```

I can see it can find the right shared object file just fine

**Inside Docker - ldd**

```
root@200f0fb753fc:/opt/bin# ldd ./run_bin
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd54576000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fd02fb46000)
    libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007fd02f8b9000)
    libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007fd02f3ee000)
    libboost_regex.so.1.70.0 => /usr/lib/libboost_regex.so.1.70.0 (0x00007fd02f131000)
    libboost_thread.so.1.70.0 => /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.70.0 (0x00007fd02ef0d000)
    libboost_filesystem.so.1.70.0 => /usr/lib/libboost_filesystem.so.1.70.0 (0x00007fd02ecf1000)
    libboost_iostreams.so.1.70.0 => /usr/lib/libboost_iostreams.so.1.70.0 (0x00007fd02eae2000)
    libboost_date_time.so.1.70.0 => /usr/lib/libboost_date_time.so.1.70.0 (0x00007fd02e8d0000)
    libaerospike.so => /usr/lib/libaerospike.so (0x00007fd02e61c000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fd02e293000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fd02e07b000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd02dc8a000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd0304dc000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fd02da86000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fd02d6e8000)


root@200f0fb753fc:/opt/bin# find / -name "libboost_iostreams.so.1.70.0"
/usr/lib/libboost_iostreams.so.1.70.0
```

Is there an option I can set on cmake to enable running this on another environment ?

Or is what I am trying to do fundamentally wrong ?

Comment: Are you building your source with Docker (when it builds the image), or are you building it outside and then installing it?

Comment: Building it outside and COPY into the docker image - same version of boost used on both

Comment: Why not build it in your Dockerfile? Then there will be no cross platform issues.

Comment: Your Dockerfile could even pull you code from SCM.

Comment: I am trying to keep the docker image as small as possible for resource reasons. I aim to build elsewhere and have a docker image with the bare minimum to run the binary. Adding all the dependencies for building bloats the image

Comment: You can throw away your build directory at the end.

Comment: You can also mount an external directory into the container so the build doesn't happen in the image.

Comment: the source / build folder isnt an issue but the dependencies for building : cmake, make, gcc, all 3rd party lib.a, etc

Comment: Perhaps you could create a very similar container to build within (same platform), then transfer the build output to a second runtime container.

Comment: Maybe three Dockerfiles: a common base system; a build container based on that base; and a runtime container also based upon it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I am aware of for building a binary in a small docker image is to a [use multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) `Dockerfile` with an [alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine?tab=description) container.

Using a `multi-stage build` your `Dockerfile` can build the binary using `cmake` and whatever libraries the binary depends on in one (large "bloated") image and then simply copy the executable and whatever files it requires into a clean (small) `alpine` image. For example:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine:3.10 AS build

# Load build packages
RUN apk --update add --no-cache \
  build-base \
  cmake \
  boost boost-dev

# The cmake boost variables
ENV BOOST_INCLUDEDIR /usr/include
ENV BOOST_LIBRARYDIR /usr/lib

WORKDIR /opt

COPY . <project-name>

WORKDIR /opt/<project-name>

RUN mkdir build \
 && cd build \
 && cmake \
    -DBOOST_INCLUDEDIR=${BOOST_INCLUDEDIR} \
    -DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR=${BOOST_LIBRARYDIR} \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    ..
 && make

# Create a clean alpine image for the binary
FROM alpine:3.10

# Copy the binary into the clean alpine image
COPY --from=build /opt/<project-name>/build/<binary-name> /bin/<binary-name>

# Copy the required library files into the clean alpine image
COPY --from=build /usr/lib/<library-names>.* /usr/lib/

# Run binary on entry
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/<binary-name>"]
```

**Build Command**

```
docker build . -t <image-name>:<ver>
```

Docker creates two images: the large image where it built your binary and the smaller (tagged) image containing just the binary and it's dependencies.

Note: `alpine:3.10` `apk` installs `boost` 1.69.0 libraries.
You may need to build the specific version of `boost` that you require in the first image and copy the relevant `.so` files over to the second image.

Comment: Unfortunately the project I am working on is dependant on boost 1.70 which isn't easily installed, it requires to be built from source. My current solution is similar to yours above however I get the boost source tarball and build it myself within the docker image. Then copy the artefacts over to the running image for dynamic linking.

Comment: I was looking to see if it was possible to configure the linkage within boost so that it is not dependant on the same exact .so libraries so I can use binaries built locally as well as within docker for better developer debugging.  With your solution the so are the same as they come from the apt package so it would work in this re guard